# Angular: Communication between controller and directive in a testable way?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I just started learning Angular and I'm trying to use it to build a file uploader which allows me to drag files to it and they will be uploaded. Relatively simple. But I'm kind of unsure on how to communicate between my controller and my directive and have it be testable. My first thought was to do something like this:

```
angular.module('UploadApp', [])
.controller('UploadController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.files = [];

    $scope.$watch('files', function() {
        //TODO: Upload the files somehow, I haven't written the service to do this yet
    }, true);
}])

.directive('UploaderDropzone', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            files: '=UploaderFiles'
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            function addFile(file) {
                if (file.type && (file.type.indexOf('image/') === 0 ||
                                  file.type.indexOf('video/') === 0)) {

                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.files.push(file);
                    });
                }
            }

            scope.watch('files', function() {
                //TODO: Do something to display the status of the uploads
            }, true);

            element.on('dragenter dragover', function(event) {
                element.addClass('hover');
                event.preventDefault();
            });

            element.on('dragleave drop', function(event) {
                var files = event && ((event.target && event.target.files) || 
                                      (event.dataTransfer && event.dataTransfer.files));

                if (files) {
                    [].forEach.call(files, function(file) {
                        addFile(file);
                    });
                }

                element.removeClass('hover');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And then in the template:

```
<div ng-controller="UploadController">
    <div uploader-dropzone uploader-files="files"></div>
</div>
```

I was planning to just wrap the files in an object that would let me communicate the upload progress, success status back to the directive too, etc. But I don't know how I'm going to test the this code since it seems like it's going to be a pain to trigger the code inside the $watch? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can use ng-model in your directive, from your point I can understand that what you want to catch values of files. 
Code will be like
   .directive('UploaderDropzone', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            files: '=UploaderFiles'
        },
      link: function(scope, element,ngmodel) {

or you can use some service to communicate between the two like below
myModule.directive('myComponent', function(mySharedService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: function($scope, $attrs, mySharedService) {

I have found one example for the above approach, may be that can help you in a more better way.  try this JS code.

var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
`myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) {`
`var sharedService = {};`

'sharedService.message = '';

```
sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
};
myModule.directive('myComponent', function(mySharedService) {
return {


controller: function($scope, $attrs, mySharedService) {
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
```

$scope.message = 'Directive: ' + mySharedService.message;

```
});
    },
    replace: true,
    template: '<input>'
};
});
function ControllerZero($scope, sharedService) {
$scope.handleClick = function(msg) {
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast(msg);
};
$scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {
    $scope.message = sharedService.message;
});
}
```